# MS Access-Return Record Below Current Record

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am very new to Access, and what I am trying to do seems like it should be very simple, but I can't seem to get it.

I am a structural engineer by trade and am making a database to design buildings.

My Diaphragm Analysis Table includes the fields "Floor_Name", "Story_Number", "Wall_Left", and "Wall_Right".  I want to write a new query that looks in another query called "Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection" and pulls information from it based on input from Diaphragm Analysis. I want to take the value in "Wall_Right" (SW01), find the corresponding value in "Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection", and report the "Elastic_Deflection" corresponding to the "Story_Below" instead of the "Story_Number" in the Diaphragm Analysis Table. In the case where "Story_Number" = 1, "Story_Below" will be 0 and I want the output to be 0.

Same procedure for "Wall_Left", but I'm just taking it one step at a time.

It seems that I need to use a "DLookup" in the expression builder with TWO criteria, one that Wall_Right = Shear_Wall and one that Story_Number = Story_Below, but when I try this I just get errors.

"Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection" includes shearwalls for all three stories, i.e. it starts at SW01 and goes through SWW for Story Number 3 and then starts again at SW01 for Story Number 2, and so on until Story Number 1.  I only show a part of the query results in the image, but rest assured, there are "Elastic_Deflection" values for story numbers below 3.

Here is my attempt in the Expression Builder:

Right_Defl_in: IIf(IsNull([Diaphragm_Analysis]![Wall_Right]),0,DLookUp("[Elastic_Deflection_in]","[Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection]","[Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection]![Story_Below]=" & [Diaphragm_Analysis]![Story_Number]))

I know my join from Diaphragm_Analysis "Wall_Left" and "Wall_Right" must include all records from Diaphragm_Analysis and only those from "Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection"![Shear_Walls] where the joined fields are equal, but that's about all I know.

Please let me know if I need to include more information or send out the database file.

Thanks for your help.

[Diaphragm Analysis (Input Table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKvXf.jpg)

[Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection (Partial Image of Query)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsA8K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is that you can and should join to `Diaphragm_Analysis` twice, first time to get the `Story_Below` value and second to use it to get the corresponding `Elastic_Deflection` value.

To handle the special case where `Story_Below` is zero, I would write a separate query (only requires one join this time) and '`OR` together' the two queries using the `UNION` set operation (note the following SQL is untested):

```
SELECT swid.Floor_Name,
       swid.Story_Number,
       swid.Wall_Left, 
       da2.Elastic_Deflection AS Story_Below_Elastic_Deflection
  FROM ( Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection swid
         INNER JOIN Diaphragm_Analysis da1
            ON da1.ShearWall = swid.Wall_Left )
         INNER JOIN Diaphragm_Analysis da2
            ON da2.ShearWall = swid.Wall_Left
               AND da2.Story_Number = da1.Story_Below
UNION
SELECT swid.Floor_Name,
       swid.Story_Number,
       swid.Wall_Left, 
       0 AS Story_Below_Elastic_Deflection
  FROM Shear_Wall_incremental_Deflection swid
       INNER JOIN Diaphragm_Analysis da1
          ON da1.ShearWall = swid.Wall_Left
 WHERE da1.Story_Below = 0;
```

I've assumed that there is no data where `Story_Number` is zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I copy this in to the SQL editor in Access, it indicates there is a syntax error in the FROM clause.  Since I don't know SQL really at all and I've been trying to get by with the GUI "spiderweb" way of joining fields, I'm not sure of the best way to debug this.  Do people write SQL in Notepad ++ or a similar environment and then copy in to Access?  I would be interested in hearing your opinion on this.

Comment: @nikenned: I had a parenthesis in the wrong place. You guessed correctly: I wrote this in a text editor!